# What happens if the tokenURI api serves a different metadata?

Tags: tokens, erc-721, nft, ethereumj

The way to reference the actual payload of the NFT is a centralized endpoint. When I create the NFT I might provision an API with an endpoint that serves a particular piece of data. What's to stop me (or anyone) to modify the endpoint after the token is sold?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing.

That's one of the reasons why services such as IPFS are preferred. With IPFS you can't change the contents while keeping the same URL.